# How do Ethernet controllers show activity with the LED indicator?

Tags: ethernet, indicator

Ethernet controllers usually have an "activity" LED which blinks in some sort of correspondence with the packets traversing the port.

I'm wondering how the controller decides when to turn the LED on and off.  It's not a random or timed flashing when data is being transmitted - it is somehow linked to the data transmissions.  But the individual transmissions would likely happen much faster than our eyes could see (or at least it would look like extremely fast "blips" on the LED, or the LED would just appear to be illuminated solid).

How do these controllers convert the extremely fast pulses to something that resembles "activity" to our brains?

I remember seeing somewhere (some odd piece of hardware) that the indicator speed could be adjusted, but I can't remember where I saw that, or how it applied to the port.

Comment: One example: https://docs.cumulusnetworks.com/cumulus-linux/Monitoring-and-Troubleshooting/Monitoring-System-Hardware/Network-Switch-Port-LED-and-Status-LED-Guidelines/ Overlall it is displaying some *status* defined by the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do these controllers convert the extremely fast pulses to something that resembles "activity" to our brains?

That's pretty much up to the controllers. But yeah, you can savely assume that every packet that the MAC layer detects turns on the LED, and just resets a counter to full value, and that this counter is counted down with a fixed clock, and when it turns zero, the LED turns off.

Or some variation thereoff that allows short packets to be seen.

Maybe throw in a state machine that allows for "blinking" in case of prolonged activity. Just some cheap digital logic in the fabric.

Comment: I just imagine some guy sitting there making it so that as long as there is packet activity to just randomly blink the LED.

Comment: Typically the LEDs are controlled by the PHY rather than the MAC, and the PHYs I've seen have several different LED modes to choose from (selected via MDIO registers or pin straps)